# Decentralized E-Authentication System for Student Portal with Ethereum-based Decentralized Identity Management and Access Control

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, metamask, authentication

I was given a final year project to build a Decentralized E-Authentication System for Student Portal with Ethereum-based Decentralized Identity Management and Access Control.  I'm new to web3, please who can help out?

Comment: I'd recommend to start learning web3. You could start by Ethereum home page https://ethereum.org/en/web3/.